# Request client login credentials - Marketing agency

Tags: twitter, ads

As a marketer I run campaigns on twitter for my clients. This requires me to login with their account (asking them manually for their username and password) and then proceed to setup their ads.twitter account. Then needing them to fill in their credit card details etc. This is not an ideal process! There has to be a better way to do this?

Is there an easy way to login in as one of my client's accounts on twitter without needing to request their username and password?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to use [TweetDeck Teams](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/introducing-tweetdeck-teams).  They can grant your account limited access to post on their behalf.

I'm not sure if it will allow you access to their payment screens though.